Copilot metrics issue
When I use new REST API endpoints for GitHub Copilot usage metrics, it works for ORG usage.
When I try for any TEAM like this:
curl -L \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer <YOUR-TOKEN>" \
  -H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" \
  https://api.github.com/orgs/ORG/team/TEAM_SLUG/copilot/usage

It is always empty.
What am I missing?

It's not you
See githubs blog post from May 9th
https://github.blog/changelog/2024-05-09-github-copilot-metrics-updates/
specifically the section
Pausing access to Team slicing in the GitHub Copilot Metrics API.
that method is out of production presently, it wasnt working correctly.
